# Changing column values with a function

Tags: r

Relatively new to R I am hoping to use this to look into better understanding function syntax and structure. I have read [the UCLA tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/intro_function.htm), but I am not seeing as much around dataframe manipulation. I have an `ifelse` that creates a new column, which is then multiplied by the data set weights. This will be repeated a number of times so I am trying to write a function. Any help, critical or supportive, always appreciated.

The manual code below is working fine (output at bottom).

```
# Step 2
f$health <- ifelse(f$qintrvyr == 2014 & f$qintrvmo < 4, f$healthcq,
    ifelse(f$qintrvyr == 2015 & f$qintrvmo < 4, f$healthpq,
         f$healthpq + f$healthcq) )

# Step 3
f$myvar <- f$health * f$finlwt21
```

However, when I try to replicate I am clearly doing something wrong because I am getting the following error:

```
Error in ifelse(df$qintrvyr == 2014 & df$qintrvmo < 4, df$oldvarcq, ifelse(df$qintrvyr ==  : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
```

Here is the function:

```
convert <- function(data, oldvarcq, oldvarpq, newvar){
  df <- data
  df$newvar <- ifelse(df$qintrvyr == 2014 & df$qintrvmo < 4, df$oldvarcq,
                   ifelse(df$qintrvyr == 2015 & df$qintrvmo < 4, df$oldvarpq,
                          df$oldvarpq + df$oldvarcq) )
  df$newvar <- df$newvar * df$finlwt21
  return(df)
}
# test the function
test <- convert(f, foodcq, foodpq, food_wt_spend)
```

This would be the desired output using a partial example of the df columns (where `myvar` would be `food_wt_spend`, `healthcq` would be `foodcq` ...):

```
health qintrvyr qintrvmo healthcq healthpq
1 2205.0     2014        4        0   2205.0
2  556.0     2014        4        0    556.0
3   72.0     2014        4        0     72.0
4 1604.4     2014        4        0   1604.4
5 2030.0     2014        4        0   2030.0
6 1080.0     2014        4        0   1080.0
7  314.7     2014        4        0    314.7
     myvar popweight finlwt21
1 42948485  4869.443 19477.77
2 13014121  5851.673 23406.69
3  1415889  4916.281 19665.12
4 20500000  3194.340 12777.36
5 40247923  4956.641 19826.56
6 18055765  4179.575 16718.30
7  6273869  4984.007 19936.03
```

Comment: The last bit of your question is somewhat unclear (I can't follow what columns your data actually has; the names don't seem to match up). Is `foodcq` supposed to be the name of a column in your data frame? If it is, you should know that `df$oldvarcq` will do one thing only: look for a column in `df` _actually called_ `oldvarcq` and try to return it. It does no evaluation of what you think you've "stored" in `oldvarcq`.

Comment: Yes, foodcq is in the data frame. And I would like to be able to pass that column of interest into the function so that I can repeat the function on the different columns. The output is a subset of columns from the df.

Comment: The relevant (long, but informative) documentation is at `?Extract`. The section on "recursive list-like" objects is what you want to focus on. The take-away is that you should pass the column name as a string, `"foodcq"` and then select the column using `[[`, e.g. `df[[oldvarcq]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @joran and pointing me to `?Extract` the following works:

```
convert <- function(data, oldvarcq, oldvarpq, newvar){
  df <- data
  df[[newvar]] <- ifelse(df$qintrvyr == 2014 & df$qintrvmo < 4, df[[oldvarcq]],
                      ifelse(df$qintrvyr == 2015 & df$qintrvmo < 4, df[[oldvarpq]],
                             df[[oldvarpq]] + df[[oldvarcq]]) )
  df[[newvar]] <- df[[newvar]] * df$finlwt21
  return(df)
}
```